# Can we initialize variables in 'it' block of jasmine.?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I tried to initialize variables like

`var a = 4;`

in **it** block

it started saying that "**Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.**"

why ??

Comment: Its rather difficult to determine the issue with current code. We would need more info

Comment: @Shyam, Can you please share your entire code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we initialize variables in 'it' block of jasmine.?

Yes.

> it started saying that "Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow."

Your `var` statement is not the cause of this error.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can initialize variable within '**it**' block and that is not causing spec timout error. Include below code in your '**config**' file and increase the '**defaultTimeoutInterval**' value if you still get the same error after including the below code

**code**

```
jasmineNodeOpts?: {
  /**
  * Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
  */
  defaultTimeoutInterval?: 95000
};
```